# python encryption function not working

Tags: python, encryption, aes

I'm trying to write a simple encryption function with python. I get an error message every time I run it saying "encryption is not defined," but it is. Can I please get some help as to why this function is not working. Thanks very much!!! Here is the code:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64
import os


def encryption (privateInfo):
    BLOCK_SIZE = 16
    PADDING = '{'

    pad = lambda s: s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * PADDING

    EncodeAES = lambda c, s: base64.b64encode(c.encrypt (pad(s)))

    secret = os.urandom(BLOCK_SIZE) 
    print 'encryption key: ', secret

    cipher = AES.new(secret)

    encoded = EncodeAES(cipher, privateInfo)

    print 'Encrypted string: ', encoded
```

and the error message I get is:

```
>>> encryption('secret message that nobody should read')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    encryption('secret message that nobody should read')
NameError: name 'encryption' is not defined
```

Comment: Import your file after spawning the Python shell (`import file.py`), or run it directly from the command line: `python file.py`

Comment: When I run python AES.py from the command line it says invalid syntax

Comment: Now that you're running the code from your file, this error indicates that you have an issue in your syntax in your actual file. Re-work your question to indicate the error message you're receiving now.

Comment: Why do I get the feeling this isn't going to print anything.. I can't quite place my finger on why though

Comment: @esqew: Why did you down vote my question? I'm asking because I don't know what I did wrong and I don't wan't to repeat the same mistake in the future. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Isaac That fixed the problem! Thanks very much for your help!!!!

Comment: What did? @LeighaBrown

Answer (score 0):

I’m pretty sure the problem you have with syntax is that you’re using `print` like this:

```
print 'something'
```

While this is ok in Python 2, it’s not in python 3, so if you use python 3, you need to use parentheses:

```
print('something')
```

or if you want to add something:

```
print('key', 'hello')
print('key: %s' %(4))
print('secret: {}, key: {}'.format('lol', '$'))
```

Which outputs:

```
keyhello
key: 4
secret: lol, key: $
```